# Prolog Define Predicates

Tags: prolog

Define a predicate that converts a number of minutes into the corresponding hours and minutes by recursively subtracting 60 from the number of minutes and incrementing the number of hours. An example of using the rule is:

```
?- mins_to_hours_and_mins(124, H, M).
H=2 M=4
```

Comment: And what have you tried?

Answer (score -5, accepted):

Try this one :) The main idea is to accumulate number of hours in the predicate min by subtracting 60 from total time and when the total time is lower than 60 we can unify counted hours from accumulator with H variable and rest of time with M variable.

```
minutes(X,H,M):-                     %main predicate
    min(X,0,H,M).

min(X,H,ResultH,ResultM):-           %ending condition of recursion
    X<60,
    ResultH is H,                    %unification with counted hours
    ResultM is X.

min(X,H,ResultM,ResultH):-           %recursive predicate
    X >= 60,
    X2 is X-60, H2 is H+1,           %subtracting from total time
    min(X2,H2,ResultM,ResultH).
```

Comment: I came up something like that.                          Func (N, H, M) :-
N < 60, 
 H is 0,
M is N. 

Func (N, H, M) :- 
N2 is N - 60, 
Func(N2, H2, M):- 
H is H2 + 1.

Comment: You have no recursive call in your code, also you cant think of variables in prolog like of variables in imperative programming, because once you assign value to the variable in prolog you cannot change it, thats why you have to use unification. I would advice to read about recursion, unification and so one from this tutorial at first :) http://www.learnprolognow.org/lpnpage.php?pageid=online